# SQL Query to select multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have the following tables:

```
projects: id, name, language
          1 |test | php
          2 |test | java
          3 |hello| php


attrs:  id, name,      value,   tb1_id
        1  | status    | finish | 1
        2  | reference | 2      | 1
```

I need a query to select all projects, which have a attribute "reference" to another project and "status" finish.

example output:

```
id, name      
1 |test
```

Could you help me?

Comment: BTW, the id column in your attrs table appears to serve no purpose

Comment: @Strawberry A unique primary key is if nothing else often useful for more complex queries, such as removing duplicate attributes.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson A compound natural PK can be formed on the entity (tb1_id) and attribute (name), in which case the scenario you describe would not occur. In any case, where a surrogate key is used, best practice requires a natural UNIQUE (compound) key to be formed alongside.

Comment: @Strawberry I see what you're saying, and you have a good point in that a natural key is very (more) useful in that case. I guess I'm just a surrogate key type person, I've almost always lived to regret skimping on them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- group the joined tables, filtering such groups with suitable aggregate functions within the `HAVING` clause:

  ```
  SELECT   projects.id, projects.name
  FROM     projects
      JOIN attrs ON attrs.tb1_id = projects.id
  GROUP BY projects.id
  HAVING   SUM(attrs.name='reference')
       AND SUM(attrs.name='status' AND attrs.value='finish')
  ```
- or else join `attrs` multiple times:

  ```
  SELECT   p.id, p.name
  FROM     projects AS p
      JOIN attrs    AS r ON  r.tb1_id = p.id
                         AND r.name   = 'reference'
      JOIN attrs    AS s ON  s.tb1_id = p.id
                         AND s.name   = 'status'
  WHERE    s.value = 'finish'
  ```

Comment: your 1. query works, can you edit so, so i get also the id of the references project?

Comment: @AlexanderG.: If you want that, you're probably better off using the second query (and adding `r.value` to the select list).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.id, P.name
FROM projects P inner join attrs A on P.id = a.tb1_id
WHERE (A.name = 'status' AND value = 'finish')
UNION
SELECT P.id, P.name
FROM attrs A INNER JOIN projects P ON A.value = P.id
WHERE A.name='reference'
```

See the result in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a94/9)

Comment: I think it should be  A.value='finish'

Comment: Because `value` is not an ambiguous column (e.g. it only occurs in the attrs table) you can put `value='finish'` instead of `A.value='finish'`. But it works both ways

Comment: The problem is, it's possible that other attributes, e.g. name="created" also can the value ="finish".
It's possible to say only name="status" should be value="finish"?

Comment: I updated my answer, I misread your question. The query now results in all the projects which have an attribute with a name status and the value finish

Comment: You're not taking the `reference` attribute into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM projects p 
INNER JOIN (SELECT tb1_id, MAX(IF(a.name = 'status', a.value, '')) attrStatus, MAX(IF(a.name = 'reference', a.value, '')) attrReference
                FROM attrs a GROUP BY tb1_id) A ON p.id = A.tb1_id AND A.attrStatus = 'finish' 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM projects p1 WHERE A.attrReference = p1.id)
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a94/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  1 | test |
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join `attrs` twice, once for each attribute;

```
SELECT p.*, ref_attr.value reference FROM projects p
JOIN attrs ref_attr  ON ref_attr.tb1_id = p.id
                    AND ref_attr.name = 'reference'
JOIN attrs stat_attr ON stat_attr.tb1_id = p.id
                    AND stat_attr.name = 'status'
                    AND stat_attr.value = 'finish'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1a458/3).